# See referenced build from another builds (pipelines) in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to delete some legacy builds in Azure DevOps, but I could not find all their parent builds that trigger them. I want to see their references. This is applicable for task groups, but I could not find this functionality for builds.

From:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops

> In the References tab you can expand lists of all the build and release pipelines, and other task groups, that use (reference) this task group. This is useful to ensure changes do not have unexpected effects on other processes.

Is there a way to see build references from the UI (no YAML)?
We are using pipelines with **Trigger Build** tasks in them.

[image]

Comment: Cannot find the `Trigger Test Build` task, do you mean the `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` Task or `Trigger Build Task`? It's recommended to provide a screenshot of your task to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thank you, you are right (good catch), it was Trigger Build Task indeed, I added image and updated the task name. We also use Trigger Test Build Task but it is a custom task group.

Comment: `Trigger Build Task` will use "Personal Access Token" by default to trigger the new build. It works same with manually trigger the new build by the user. Hence, you can not determine the parent pipeline in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete some legacy builds in Azure DevOps, but I could not find all their parent builds that trigger them.

If you use [pipeline resource trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) in yaml, besides you can find the trigger info from yaml definition, you can also find the trigger build in the current build result page. You can click on the link and it will navigate to the trigger build.
[image]

If you use classic UI editor in the build, there should be trigger build completed definition as below:

[image]

In addition, there are [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) to find the triggered build info. You can export the info in the pipeline if you'd like.

[image]

Edit:

You are using "Trigger Build" task, the task will use `Personal access token` by default to trigger the new build. It works same as the user manually trigger the new build. In this scenario, you cannot's find the parent pipeline.

Comment: Hi, is there any update? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Unfortunately your answer is not helping me. We do not use pipeline resource trigger.

Comment: Hi @K.B. i have updated the comment, please check. Let me know if you have any queries.